# Send informations with Bluetooth in Swift IOS language

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, core-bluetooth

I'm actually in informatics school and I have some trouble with the connection between my own self signed app coded in Swift(Xcode 11.3 and for IOS 13.2 device) and a BLE module SH-HC-08 plugged on an Arduino. *(UUID : FE60E626-C58C-69F5-324F-43C7C409A93D)*

I'm totally new into swift language and self-learning this way of thinking in this language.

I'm using CoreBluetooth to detect if the Bluetooth on my iPhone is On or off.
I can't actually check if my peripheral is detected, and can't send any information by my app.
(don't understand how to configure the methods in CoreBluetooth)

I downloaded apps caled *LightBlue* and *BluetoothLE* on app store. The first one give me fews information about my Bluetooth device and the second one allow me to sends Ascii Strings to my Arduino by my Bluetooth module.

LightBlue information 1:

[image]

LightBlue information 2:

[image]

BluetoothLE app:

[image]

As I said before, i already :

- Import CoreBluetooth
- Add CBCentralManagerDelegate & CBPeripheralDelegate to my class ViewController
- instantiate CBCentralManager and CBPeripheral
- setup the *centralManagerDidUpdateState* function

  CoreBluetooth code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth



var texteEnvoyer:String?
var test = false



class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    
    var manager:CBCentralManager!
    var module : CBPeripheral!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelConnection: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var switchConnection: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        refresh()
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        
        
    }
    
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
     {
         if(central.state == .poweredOff)
         {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Bluetooth", message: "Le bluetooth est déconnecté, veuillez l'activer et vous connecter au module.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            test = false
         }
         if(central.state == .poweredOn)
         {
             test = true
         }
         refresh()
     }
```

I tried to play with the others methods like *didDiscoverPeripheral* or *didConnected* but I don't understand what i do and can't find any help to send information (preferred in String) by a self made application with bluetooth.

I tried that to  discover my module but I don't have any "print" in my logs and don't know if my request was done or not... if I do it well or not too.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("Name: \(peripheral.name)")
        self.module = peripheral
        self.module.delegate = self
        
        if(peripheral.name == "SG-HC-08"){
            manager.stopScan()
            manager.connect(self.module, options: nil)
            print(peripheral.name)
        }
    }
```

Someone have any experience with that or any help to give it will help me so much.
Thanks

Comment: generally with questions that involve specific requirements. It is necessary for you to provide some code as to what you have already have tried. By providing some of the code you have already tried it will greatly increase  your chances of your question being answered. For example you said "I cant actually check if my peripheral is detected, and cant send any information by my app". The community cant help debug if we cant see your code. By sharing the code you are using to do this operation will help the community answer your question.

Comment: I tried to add some code to be honest I don't know if its the good way to do it ...

Comment: It does not matter if it is the wrong way to do it... its how you learn :)

Comment: that's right :)

Comment: are you getting any errors when you try and run the code ? Does your app crash ? Or does nothing just happen. ALSO: Add a print statement into your code where you call "manager.connect(self.module, options: nil) " simply say print("reached here") if it prints it means the code was executed. Simple debug steps

Comment: no error, no crashing, but the log doesn't show anything about the peripheral... :/
I add a print after the discover function and nothing append ... it didn't even reached this function ...

Comment: I fixed your images, but for readability it's better to paste code, do not show a screenshot. See also [ask].

Comment: Thanks yeah it isn't readable anymore haha I will try ti fix that

Comment: Your not starting a scan, which means that you'll never discover anything. This is very basic Bluetooth, which suggests you're at the very beginning of a somewhat complicated topic, and I expect you to have many more questions than can be answered in this forum. I suggest starting with the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide which walks through how to get started. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jikko,

I would be careful with using Global Variables.

Your global variables are the two declared outside of your class scope.

```
var texteEnvoyer:String? 
var test = false
```

These can sometimes cause issues with your program such as memory leaks and retention. Im not saying that this is the case for you. But if you continue to develop and publish applications this may be something to rethink. Im sure for your purposes now this is totally fine.

To your point of "nothing in the console form the peripheral" we can try adding in some print statements to help us debug what is actually happening.

For starters:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager){
   //.....
   print("ENTERED THE FUNCTION")
   if(peripheral.name == "SG-HC-08"){
        manager.stopScan()
        manager.connect(self.module, options: nil)
        print("REACHED HERE")
    }
}
```

IF in the console you see "REACHED HERE" then we know the code was called and executed. However this does not mean a successful connection.

If we do not see the print statement "ENTERED THE FUNCTION" , or "REACHED HERE" then that means there is a basic error. The function was never called or executed.

I would first create a function like so:

```
func startScan(){
  if let central = manager {
    central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    print("started Scanning")
  }
}
```

And then in viewDidLoad()
call the start scan

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad(animated)
    startScan()
}
```

And then once you have discovered a peripheral use the `didDiscoverPeripheral` method (which will be called first)

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
  print("DISCOVERED PERIPHERAL", peripheral)
  // manager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
}
```

You can then connect to it once discovered.

Hope this helps

EDIT ----

try adding in these two lines to your function.

```
   peripheral.delegate = self
   peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
```

like so

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
  print("DISCOVERED PERIPHERAL", peripheral)
  // manager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
}
```

I forgot to add in the underscore "_" to the function parameters

```
func centralManager(_ central: ....) {}

--------------------^
```

Comment: Ok i will try to avoid Global variables ^^

also I tried the "beginners" debug methods :) but it doesn't show anything (in centralManager(...didDiscoverPeripheral....) ).

so I tried the startScan() and yep log show me the first print("Started scanning") but nothing else .. it seems that it don't want to enter into the function centralManager(...didDiscoverPeripheral....)

Comment: @Jikko check my update perhaps the delegates is whats missing for you. ALSO i updated the functions paramaters. they were missing a crucial underscrore

Comment: I added those 2 lines into the centralManager(_ central:.., didDiscover peripheral...) but it still don't show the "discovered peripheral" in the console.  Also I got a update a console message told me (now) that the command will only be able on poweredOn state so I putted *startScan()* into centralManagerDidUpdateState when its on and I got a devices into my logs yeeeeah I stopped the scan after an if function to stop at the right peripheral :) 
Now Step 2 connection haha I will come to you if I don't succeed myself. THANKS a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Please find some informations on how delegation (1) and BLE (2) work.

1) When you instantiate your CBCentralObject manager, you pass your view controller (self) as the *delegate* of the central manager which means that some Bluetooth events handled by your central manager *will be forwarded* to your view controller.

In your case, it seems that you didn't implement the *centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)* method which is called every time a new peripheral is discovered.

Once you get the discovered peripheral, you can continue the process with the other delegates methods

2) If you want to communicate with a BLE device you have several steps to follow:

1. discover the device
2. connect to it
3. discover services and
   characteristics

Then you can write data on any characteristic you want, or subscribe to listen to data emitted by your BLE device.

Comment: for the step 1, I did implement the centralManager(...didDiscoverPeripheral...) :) but when I tried to add some print into the function to debug myself it don't even reached the function.. :/

for the second step, thanks It help me a little bit more to understand how BLE works :)

Comment: We posted our messages at the same time, I didn't see that you used it :) I think that you forgot to start the scan with your central manager.